# Macbook's Arabic keyboard layout mistakes and missing characters!

Tags: mac, keyboard, internationalization, language, arabic

I'm familiar enough with the Arabic language, but not sure if those points down below are considered to be mistakes from apple designers or not, also I've checked with the official layout of Apple's docs and my mac device! So I'm hopping for a clear answer or more information. Thank you in advance.

**Missing characters in the keyboard layout.**

- Arabic decimal separator `٫` `Shift+ن or K` `U+066B` is not labeled!
- Arabic thousands separator `٬` `Shift+م or L` `U+066C` is not labeled!
- Apostrophe `'` `Shift+ظ or Z` `U+0027` is not labeled!

**Incorrect layout**

**Guillemet/Angle quotes** `« »`

The layout is reversed! (Not sure about this as Arabic is RTL)

`Shift+ش or A` and `Shift+س or S` `U+00AB` and `U+00BB`

- Left-pointing double angle quotation mark `«` `U+00AB` when pressed it gives a `»`.
- Right-pointing double angle quotation mark `»` `U+00BB` when pressed it gives a `«`.

This is correct in English language since it is LTR but in case of Arabic it makes some confusion!

Appreciate any help or a clarification.

Comment: I don't understand your "Missing Characters" comment.  On my MacOS using the "arabic" input source, Shift k, l, z show the characters in Keyboard Viewer and produce them when I type, with the values 0027, 066b, 066c.  Nothing is missing. Are you talking about what is printed on the keys of the hardware keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of your question is to recommend that the printing on Apple's hardware Arabic keyboard be changed, the best place to do that is via their [Feedback Channel](http://www.apple.com/feedback).